# Remove duplicate strings from a list

Tags: common-lisp

I have a dead simple Common Lisp question: what is the idiomatic way of removing duplicates from a list of strings?

`remove-duplicates` works as I'd expect for numbers, but not for strings:

```
* (remove-duplicates '(1 2 2 3))

(1 2 3)

* (remove-duplicates '("one" "two" "two" "three"))

("one" "two" "two" "three")
```

I'm guessing there's some sense in which the strings aren't equal, most likely because although "foo" and "foo" are apparently identical, they're actually pointers to different structures in memory.  I think my expectation here may just be a C hangover.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to tell remove-duplicates how it should compare the values. By default, it uses `eql`, which is not sufficient for strings. Pass the `:test` function as in:

```
(remove-duplicates your-sequence :test #'equal).
```

(Edit to address the question from the comments): As an alternative to `equal`, you could use `string=` in this example. This predicate is (in a way) less generic than `equal` and it might (could, probably, possibly, eventually...) thus be faster. A real benefit might be, that `string=` can tell you, if you pass a wrong value:

```
(equal 1 "foo")
```

happily yields `nil`, whereas

```
(string= 1 "foo")
```

gives a `type-error` condition. Note, though, that

```
(string= "FOO" :FOO)
```

is perfectly well defined (`string=` and its friend are defined in terms of "string designators" not strings), so type safety would go only so far here.

The standard `eql` predicate, on the other hand, is almost never the right way to compare strings. If you are familiar with the Java language, think of `eql` as using `==` while `equal` (or `string=`, etc.) calling the `equals(Object)` method. Though `eql` does some type introspection (as opposed to `eq`, which does not), for most (non-numeric) lisp types, `eql` boils down to something like a pointer comparison, which is not sufficient, if you want to discriminate values based on what they actually contain, and not merely on where in memory they are located.

For the more Pythonic inclined, `eq` (and `eql` for non-numeric types) is more like the `is`  operator, whereas `equal` is more like `==` which calls `__eq__`.

Comment: I would be tempted to use STRING= rather than EQUAL.

Comment: Why? What is the difference?

Comment: STRING= compares characters using CHAR= which according to the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_chareq.htm#char-equal) "...returns true if all characters are the same; otherwise, it returns false. If two characters differ in any implementation-defined attributes, then they are not char=". I'm not sure using an implementation-defined behaviour is a better choice.

Comment: @MarcoRighele: yes, good point actually. Though (out of curiosity) -- are there still implementations which define additional character attributes? Neither SBCL nor CCL do (both use `eq` in `char=`). How about the commercial ones? Allegro? Lispworks? Didn't check CLISP.

Comment: CLISP [doesn't define any](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes.html#char-attrib). I don't know about commercial implementations but my guess is that it is mostly an historical artifact originally intended for font attributes.